# change priority in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]

I have a component that looks like this.

In the render, it is written as :

```
    <div className="experiments-list-container">
      {/* Select ID on row hover so that Link can direct it correctly*/}
      <Link 
        to={'/i/edit/' + this.state.selectedID}
        style={{ 
          textDecoration: 'none',
          color: 'black'
        }}
      >
      <List
        onRowHovered={this.getExperimentID}
        toggleSwitch={this.changeStatus}
        rowItems={this.state.experimentData}
        shouldShowItem={item => {
          return item.status === this.state.viewActive;
        }}
        viewActive={this.state.viewActive}
      />
      </Link>
```

The toggle switch is in the child component and it's used like

```
  render() {
    const dateDisplay = moment(this.props.createdAt).format('MMM YYYY');
    //alert(this.props.rowItems.status)
    if (this.state.show) {
      return (
        <tr
          className="experiment-list__row"
          onMouseOver={() => this.props.onRowHovered(this.props.rowItems.id)}
        >
          <td>{this.props.rowItems.name}</td>
          <td>{this.props.rowItems.owner}</td>
          <td>{dateDisplay}</td>
          <td className="experiment-list--col__switch">
            <Switch
              color="primary"
              checked={this.props.rowItems.status}
              onChange={this.change}
            />
          </td>
        </tr>
      );
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

I want the switch and the Link to work together, but since the switch is in the child component, it doesn't get affected. How can I separate them?

**EDIT**

parent comp

```
  changeStatus(rowID, rowStatus) {
    // close if the selected employee is clicked
    makeMutation(UpdateExperimentQuery, {
      update: {
        id: rowID,
        data: {
          status: !rowStatus,
        },
      },
    })
      .then(responseData => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.componentWillMount();
        }, 1000);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
```

child comp

```
  change() {
    this.props.toggleSwitch(this.props.rowItems.id, this.props.rowItems.status);
  }


const List = props => {
  return (
    <table className="experiment-list">
      <tbody>
        <ListHeader />
        {props.rowItems.map((data, i) => (
          <ListRow
            key={i}
            rowItems={data}
            onRowHovered={props.onRowHovered}
            toggleSwitch={props.toggleSwitch}
            shouldShowItem={props.shouldShowItem}
            viewActive={props.viewActive}
          />
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};

  render() {
    const dateDisplay = moment(this.props.createdAt).format('MMM YYYY');
    //alert(this.props.rowItems.status)
    if (this.state.show) {
      return (
        <tr
          className="experiment-list__row"
          onMouseOver={() => this.props.onRowHovered(this.props.rowItems.id)}
        >
          <td>{this.props.rowItems.name}</td>
          <td>{this.props.rowItems.owner}</td>
          <td>{dateDisplay}</td>
          <td className="experiment-list--col__switch">
            <Switch
              color="primary"
              checked={this.props.rowItems.status}
              onChange={this.change}
            />
          </td>
        </tr>
      );
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

The change just basically updates the data in the DB. I don't think it has anything to do with the priority of the component.

Comment: What do you mean by saying `want the switch and the Link to work together` ? it would be easier to help you if you share a codepen or something like that.

Comment: So when I disable the Link, the switch toggles when I click it. But when I enable the Link, it just directs me to the following link since it wraps the whole component including the switch. I want to make them separate.

Comment: I need to see `changeStatus` and `change` methods. It is hard to say anything with this data. Looks like there is a logic issue.

Comment: Please check my edit!

Comment: I've re-read your question three times now, even with the edit. I'm so confused. you say "in the child component", but there is no child.. do you mean the `rowItems` prop of `List`? You're wrapping an entire list in a `Link`? When would that ever make sense?

Comment: @azium Ok so the `<Link>` wraps a `List` component that contains the switch. WIthout the `<Link>`, the switch changes the status of the data in the ListRow when clicked. With the `<Link>`, the List is supposed to direct the user to the edit page when clicked, but in this case, clicking the switch will also direct the user to the edit page without toggling. I was asking how to make both of them work separately.

Comment: don't wrap the entire list then? just wrap the part you want to be linkable

Comment: but the switch is inside the `List` component. I was asking how to separate them.